# Anaconda Not Recognized on Windows 8.1 AFTER Adding to Path

Tags: python, anaconda

This is starting to get aggravating. I'm getting the typical "conda is not recognized as an internal or external command..." message when trying to run conda in the command line. This is a common issue, and I've found plenty of posts saying to fix it by adding both the Anaconda folder and its script folder to my path. The problem is that I've done this, my path looks like:

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3;
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\usr\bin;
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\bin;
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts;
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.1\bin;
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\redist\ia32\compiler;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\redist\intel64\compiler;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;
C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;
C:\Windows\system32;
C:\Windows;
C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;
C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;
c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;
c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologie
```

Anaconda should clearly be in there. I've tried restarting the terminal, I've tried adding the path variables by hand/from Anaconda's installer/from the terminal, I've tried restarting my computer after doing this...absolutely no luck. Does anyone have any other ideas?

Comment: Have you explicitly checked the folder `Anaconda3\Scripts` for conda.exe? Do you have 2 anaconda installations? In ProgramData\... and Users\...?

Comment: Huh...I just did and it's not there. That's really weird, I just installed the package from the official website. Is there a known reason this would happen?

Comment: Newer versions of Anaconda prefer you to use the Anaconda Prompt rather than the regular command prompt. In addition, did you specify that Anaconda should be installed for your user only, or for the whole system?

Answer (score 0):

Not enough points to comment. This is the value I added to my path:

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Scripts
```